# Have programming languages driven hardware development?

Tags: hardware, software, c

Programming language development has been influenced by hardware design. One example from [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6099) mentions how C pointers were, at least in part, influenced by the design of the PDP-11. Has the reverse taken place, where a construct provided by a language drove the development of hardware?

To be clear, I'm wondering about core language constructs, like pointers for example, rather than industry consortiums coming up with something like OpenGL then being implemented in hardware. Perhaps hardware floating-point support?

Comment: Welcome to *Retrocomputing*.  Nice question!

Comment: Similar question is also true for operating systems: inter process protection & security, paging & virtual memory, fast context switching, etc..

Comment: As a cautionary tale we should perhaps mention the [iAPX 432](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that many of the RISC processors were designed specifically to be good targets for compilers; I'm seeking a source.

Comment: @Tommy RISC CPUs are interesting case. They were designed in era where it was obvious that they'd be almost exclusively running compiled code, so were designed with compilers in mind. On the other hand, many RISC CPUs were designed with certain features and limitations that required compilers implement things they didn't have to previously.  For example, branch delay slots and pipelining required that the compiler to reorder instructions in order to generate the most efficient code. (In the end it proved CPUs can do a better job of reordering instructions than compilers.)

Comment: Quite surprised no one has mentioned Lisp machines or Java smartcards.

Comment: @chrylis Why is it surprising when both turned out to be dead-ends?

Comment: Both of those are simply hardware implementations of interpreters or virtual machines; I assumed the question was more about programming languages that changed the general evolution of hardware design. (Like, did array support lead to greater use of on-chip cache to support efficient array access?)

Comment: Re, "hardware implementation of [a] virtual machine."  That's just a long-winded way of saying, "machine." No?

Comment: This question seems to have been a good one!

Comment: Shortly after the ARM came out, I remember reading in the UK computer press of a research attempt to create an ARM-derived core that would use a language close to C as its instruction set. Never heard any more of it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_language_computer_architecture

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes and no :) It captures the idea that the hardware implementation was produced, and even conceived, after the primary software implementation of the Java/Lisp specification for how to interpret the language.

Comment: Yeah, but we called them "[Lisp _Machines_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine)" back in the day when you never heard anybody say "_virtual_ machine" unless they were talking about IBM mainframes.  (e.g., "[VM/370](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VM_(operating_system))")

Comment: @RossRidge I think that instead of proving anything about compilers and cpu, it proves that a single "team" may create a better product than multiple "teams" that are only loosely tied together (like Intel and the GCC team for instance)

Comment: Related: [Why do ARM chips have an instruction with Javascript in the name (FJCVTZS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966676/why-do-arm-chips-have-an-instruction-with-javascript-in-the-name-fjcvtzs)

Comment: Arguably, IBM AS/400 vulgo iSeries could be relevant here....

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Interesting question with an interesting answer.

First let me get one thing out of the way:

> One example from this answer mentions how C pointers were, at least in part, influenced by the design of the PDP-11

It's a myth to suggest C's design is based on the PDP-11. People often quote, for example, the increment and decrement operators because they have an analogue in the PDP-11 instruction set. This is, however, a coincidence. [Those operators were invented before the language was ported to the PDP-11](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).

There are actually two answers to this question

- processors that are targeted to a specific high level language
- processors that include features that a high level language might find useful.

In the former category we have most of the interesting eventual dead ends in computer hardware history. Perhaps the one of the earliest examples of a CPU architecture being targeted at a high level language is the [Burroughs B5000 and its successors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burroughs_large_systems). This is a family of machines targeted at Algol. In fact, there wasn't really a machine language as such that you could program in.

The B5000 had a lot of hardware features designed to support the implementation of Algol. It had a hardware stack and all data manipulations were performed on the stack. It used tagged descriptors for data so the CPU had some idea of what it was dealing with. It had a series of registers called display registers that were used to model static scope* efficiently.

Other examples of machines targeted at specific languages include the Lisp machine already mentioned, arguably the Cray series of supercomputers for Fortran - or even just Fortran loops, [the ICL 2900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICL_2900_Series) series (also block structured high level languages), some machines targeted at the Java virtual machine (some ARM processors have [hardware JVM support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle)) and many others.

One of the drivers behind creating [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computer) architectures was the observation that compilers tended to use only a small subset of the available combinations of instructions and addressing modes available on most CPU architectures, so RISC designers ditched the unused ones and filled the space previously used for complex decoding logic with more registers.

In the second category, we have individual features in processors targeted at high level languages. For example, the hardware stack is a useful feature for an assembly language programmer, but more or less essential for any language that allows recursive function calls. The processor may build features on top of that for example, many CPUs have an instruction to create a stack frame (the data structure on the stack that represents a function's parameters and local variables).

*Algol allowed you to declare functions inside other functions. Static scope reflects the way functions were nested in the program source - an inner function could access the variables and functions defined in it and in the scope in which it was defined and the scope in which that scope was defined all the way up to global scope.

Comment: Like others mentioned, there's an obvious chicken and egg problem here. Regarding the hardware stack, which side drove development? Was the hardware stack initially implemented, and then taken advantage of? Or were stacks implemented in software, and the hardware stack implemented to address this?

Comment: @Nathan I think it is most likely that the hardware stack was invented after the need for efficient stacks was identified but this was probably fairly early in the history of digital computers.

Comment: @JeremyP - since you mentioned the 2900, I'll add [MU5](http://www.cs.manchester.ac.uk/about-us/history/mu5/) , an ancestor of sorts to the 2900.

Comment: Is the B5000 a dead end ? When it supported a large company over a fair time ? But yes it was very much proprietary and from a time when suppliers didn't have the ability/or need to shrink pricing.  Is the IBM 360 a dead end ? Or for that matter the Apple Power Mac ?

Answer (score 59):

### Simply yes.

And not just a few instructions, but whole CPUs have been developed with languages in mind. Most prominent maybe Intel's 8086. Already the basic CPU was designed to support the way high level languages handle memory management, especially stack allocation and usage. With BP a separate register for stack frames and addressing was added in conjunction with short encodings for stack related addressing to make HLL programs perform. The 80186/286 went further in this direction by adding Enter/Leave instructions for stack frame handling.

While it can be said that the base 8086 was geared more toward languages like Pascal or PL/M (*1,2), later incarnations added many ways to support the now prevalent C primitives - not at least scaling factors for indices.

---

Since many answers pile now various details of CPUs where instructions may match up (or not), there are maybe two other CPUs worth mentioning: The Pascal Microengine and Rockwells 65C19 (as well as the RTX2000).

### Pascal Microengine, a CPU made for generic HLL implementaions

The **[Pascal Microengine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_MicroEngine)** was a WD MCP1600 chipset (*3) based implementation of the virtual 16 bit [UCSD p-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-code_machine#UCSD_p-Machine) processor. Contrary to what the name suggests, it wasn't tied to Pascal as a language, but a generic stack machine tailored to support concepts for HLL operations. Beside a rather simple, stack based execution, the most important part was a far reaching and comfortable management of local memory structures for functions and function linking as well as data. Modern time [Java Bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) and its interpreter as a native Bytecode CPU (e.g. PicoJava) isn't in any way a new idea (*4).

### R65C19 and N4000, CPU's enhanced or custom made for a specific language

The Rockwell [R65C19](http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/rockwell_r65c19_microcomputer.pdf) is a [6500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502) variant with added support for [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)). Its 10 new threaded code instructions (*5) implemented the core functions (like Next) of a Forth system as single machine instructions.

Forth as a language was developed with a keen eye on the way it is executed. It got more in common with Assemblers than many other HLL (*6). So it's no surprise that, already in 1983, its inventor [Charles Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Moore) created a Forth CPU called N4000 (*7).

---

*1 - Most remarkable here the string functions which make only sense in languages supporting strings as discrete data type.

*2 - Stephen Morse's [8086 primer](https://www.stevemorse.org/8086/index.html) is still a good read - especially when he talks about the finer details. Similar and quite recommended his [2008 interview](https://www.pcworld.com/article/146917/components/article.html) about the 8086 creation where he describes his approach as mostly HLL driven.

*3 - Which makes it basically a LSI-11 with different microcode.

*4 - As IT historians, we have seen each and every implementation already before, haven't we? So let's play a round of [Zork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-machine).

*5 - There are other nice additions as well, like mathematical operations that ease filter programming - after all, the 65C19/29/39 series was the heart of many modems.

*6 - The discrimination with assembler as not being a HLL and miles apart becomes quite blurry when looking close anyway.

*7 - Later sold to Harris, who developed it into the [RTX2000](http://soton.mpeforth.com/flag/jfar/vol6/no1/article1.pdf) series - with radiation hardened versions that power several [deep space probes](https://web.archive.org/web/20110204160744/http://forth.gsfc.nasa.gov/).

Comment: Intel 8086 certainly had relatively high-level instructions, but I'd chalk that to the opposite you're saying - it was so that you could write (relatively) high-level code in *assembly*. There's huge amounts of instructions that are worthless for a "high-level" language like C, but great for assembly programmers. RISC CPUs were designed for compiled languages, CISC CPUs were primarily designed for assembly programmers. Of course, in practice, compilers weren't all that good at that point, so there was a lot of blurry lines between assembly programming and something like C.

Comment: @Luaan Calling C a HLL is always borderline. And here it's even less important, as C wasn't anywhere relevant during the late 70s. Pascal and similar languages were seen as the way to go. Further, that nice complex instructions are as well a good idea for Assembler doesn't make them made for Assembler. Aach and every compiler produces assembly at last, thus directly benefiting from such operations. You may realy want to read the interview.

Comment: I'm not saying that compilers couldn't use the more complex instructions - I'm saying that those instructions were redundant. You could do the same job faster with a couple of instructions, which compilers could easily do, but assembly programmers didn't really bother with unless necessary (though granted, this was a lot more important on 386 and 486 and outright silly on Pentium+, rather than the 8086). And while I've always been on the Pascal side in the great fight, I don't think there were many differences in the required instructions between Pascal and C.

Comment: As for the interview, I don't see them talking about high-level languages and the design of 8086. Would you care to point it out more specifically?

Comment: Add the Hobbit which was designed to run C (and similar CPUs like the Bellmac and CRISP that led to Hobbit). Intel 432 was similar in concept but added tagged memory and other support for built-in Multics/Unix-like security heirarchies.

Comment: @Raffzahn C is most definitely a high level language. Although I agree it wasn't relevant in the late 70's except in Unix world.

Comment: @JeremyP If C is "**most** definitely", then assembly is as well. Mind the distinction between Assembly and machine code.

Comment: @Raffzahn Nope. C is based on a high level abstract computing model. Its statements do not map directly to a specific real computer's instruction set. Assemblers have instructions with a one to one mapping with the target CPU's instruction set. It's true that the more sophisticated assemblers blur the distinction between high and low level languages but C sits firmly on the high level side of the blurred line.

Comment: @JeremyP Sorry, but that works the other way around as well. Not every assembler statement is 1:1 mapping of a machine instruction. Some map none, other map several. Plus all the ways to define data structures as well as operations thereon. And don't get me started on Macros - which are most "Most definitly" :) an assembly language construct -aren't they? And no matter how much some try to spread dogma like that C isn't made with certain instructions in mind, history tells otherwise. C sits ratehr hard on the low level side, not at least by the way it treats memory via arbitrary pointers.

Comment: @Raffzahn Did you read the bit where I said *It's true that the more sophisticated assemblers blur the distinction between high and low level languages*? C is definitely a high level language. Its constructs are abstract and divorced from any particular machine architecture. There is no way you can look at it and say "this is an assembler" (well not unless you are being stubborn and insisting on believing in myths :-) )

Comment: @JeremyP To start with, I can relate to the stubborn part :)  It's just that 'the more sophisticated' Assemblers are standard - they were already standard before even the first line of B was imagined. Saying so is like saying "some more sophisticated C compilers can do += instead of the standard =+ and even allow void definitions" - isn't it? And yes, I see C as an Assembler. Clumsy syntax for some parts, but it works. Some restrctions apply, batteries not included.

Comment: Yes, you're right mentioning Pascal Microengine : i own a Pascaline (one of the few remaining alive here in Europe), and its core was designed to run HLL with proper optimizations, the hardware ancestor of the virtual VMs. This was the good ol' times when engineers tried to maximise machine intelligence over speed... You could expand your answer citing e.g. coprocessors used with x386.

Comment: @Benj Expanding it would open pandoras box. it's just meant to mark some milestones. Now, until now the term Pascaline was for me tied to a mechanical calculator build by Pascal. Never heard it in context of a Pascal Micro Engine (Got 3 working - two in original silver and a prototype from cancelled project for an office PC based on the Microengine.) - mind to share more information?

Comment: @Raffzahn sure ! Is there some MP on stackexchange, or some chat or whatever ?

Comment: @Benj I still haven't fully figured out the chat system here. But let me try.

Comment: @Raffzahn ok, let me know

Comment: @JeremyP: In a "traditional" C compiler, given `extern int x;`, the behavior of `x++;` would be "Take the address of `x`; and either use the environment's means of incrementing an int-sized value there or else fetch an int-sized value from there using either the environment's means of loading such a value or a combination of smaller loads, then use either an environment's means of adding 1 to a number or some other means that will never have side-effects, and then use the environment's means of writing that result back to the address of `x` (or a sequence of smaller stores).

Comment: That's doesn't offer semantics that are quite as precise as assembly language, but the underlying behavioral model is the same.  The operation `x++;` doesn't actually act on a value of type `int`, but rather on an `int`-sized sequence of bytes that are loaded, incremented, and stored using the environment's means of performing such operations.

Comment: @supercat The semantics of `x++` are precisely defined in the C standard. Everything you say is completely hidden as far as the programmer is concerned. They don't care how `x++` is implemented, nor do they need to care.    It's an abstraction and also not assembler.

Comment: @JeremyP: The Standard was written to define a language that had already been in use for more than a decade, and which could be (and often was) used as a form of "high-level assembler", **as acknowledged by the authors of the Standard** in the C99 Rationale at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf line 34 of page 2).  Why would the authors of the Standard have said such a thing if the notion of C as a "high-level assembler" was purely a myth?

Comment: [x86 as a Pascal Machine?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6959/1981)

Answer (score 45):

One interesting example of programming languages driving hardware development is the LISP machine. Since "normal" computers of the time period couldn't execute lisp code efficiently, and there was a high demand for the language in academia and research, dedicated hardware was built with the sole purpose of executing lisp code. Although lisp machines were initially developed for MIT's AI lab, they also saw sucess in [computer animation](https://web.archive.org/web/20110716211447/http://lemonodor.com/archives/000256.html).

These computers provided increased speed by using a stack machine instead of the typical register based design, and had native support for type checking lisp types. Some other important hardware features aided in garbage collection and closures. Here's a series of slides that go into more detail on the design: [Architecture of Lisp Machines (PDF)](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~mflatt/past-courses/cs6510/public_html/lispm.pdf) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20170829231741/https://www.cs.utah.edu/~mflatt/past-courses/cs6510/public_html/lispm.pdf)).

The architecture of these computers are specialized enough that in order to run c code, the c source is transpiled into lisp, and then run normally. The [Vacietis](https://github.com/vsedach/Vacietis) compiler is an example of such a system.

Comment: It's notable that there has been a few talks about CPUs specifically designed to run the intermediate languages of platforms like Java or .NET, though to my knowledge the attempts were mostly failures. And of course, then there's the VLIW architectures that were entirely designed for smart compilers.

Comment: Interesting to hear about C being  transpiled into lisp! Thanks!

Comment: "and there was a high demand for the language" - citation needed. :-) My impression is more that there was a loud academic lisp fandom pushing for hardware that would make their language relevant to the real world, and very little interest from the real world in buying such machines or using lisp.

Comment: @R.. I clarified where that high demand was coming from. Better?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle "Jazelle DBX (Direct Bytecode eXecution) is an extension that allows some ARM processors to execute Java bytecode in hardware"

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE high demand ? It was good enough to create an  industry and having yahoo pay two guys 49 million for a company (viaweb). They designed and wrote a platform for the Internet and did deliver it in compared with what it would have taken if done in Perl in a very short time.  Though the language is a bit hard and it requires a lot of the user.

Answer (score 22):

Yes.  Case in point, the VAX.  The instruction set design was influenced by the requirements of the compiled languages of the day.  For example, the orthogonality of the ISA; the provision of instructions that map to language constructs such as 'case' statements (in the numbered-case sense of Hoare's original formulation, not the labelled-case of C), loop statements, and so on.

[VAX Architecture Ref](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/vax/archSpec/EK-VAXAR-RM-001_Arch_May82.pdf) - see the *Introduction*.

I am not claiming the VAX is unique in this respect, just an example I know a little about. As a second example, I'll mention the Burroughs B6500 'display' registers.  A display, in 1960s speak, is a mechanism for efficient uplevel references. If your language, such as Algol60, permits declaration of nested procedures to any depth, then arbitrary references to the local variables of different levels of enclosing procedure require special handling.  The mechanism used (the 'display') was invented for KDF9 Whetstone Algol by Randell and Russell, and described in their book [Algol 60 Implementation](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/book/Randell_ALGOL_60_Implementation_1964.pdf/view). The [B6500](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~eurip/papers/BurroughsB6500stack.pdf) incorporates that into hardware:

> The B6500/B7500 contains a network of Display Registers (D0 through
>   D31) which are caused to point at the appropriate MSCW (Fig. 5). The
>   local variables of all procedures global to the current procedure are
>   addressed in the B6500/B7500 relative to the Display Registers.

Comment: as well as more registers for local variables, and large, regular address space rather than smaller banks that can be activated one at a time..

Comment: My understanding is that VAX's powerful addressing modes and flexible instruction operands were mostly useful for human programmers at the time; VAX was a poor compiler target because compilers at the time weren't smart enough to take advantage of the funky stuff, and used more but simpler instructions (which VAX couldn't run faster). I haven't used VAX, but providing high-level-like functionality in hardware instructions directly (so your asm can "look" like high-level control constructs) sounds much more beneficial to humans than compilers. Or maybe they thought it would be good, but wasn't.

Comment: i.e. maybe VAX architects hoped that compilers could be made that would translate high-level code to similar-looking asm using these features, but the discovery that that wasn't the case is what led to RISC designs, which were good at chewing through the multiple simple instructions compilers most naturally generated.

Comment: I wasn't thinking so much of the 'fancy' instructions so much as I was thinking of the orthogonality of the instruction set; pretty much any operand specifiers could be used with any instruction. That makes compilation easier because fewer special cases.  The main language I used on VMS, BLISS-32, had a compiler that was way better at using funky addressing modes than I was. You can interpret that how you like :-)

Answer (score 19):

## Some manufacturers have directly admitted such

The first page of the Intel 8086 data sheet lists the processor's features, which include

> - Architecture Designed for Powerful Assembly Language and Efficient High Level Languages

In particular, C and other high-level languages use the stack for arguments and local variables.  The 8086 has both a stack pointer (SP) and a frame pointer (BP) which address memory using the stack segment (SS) rather than other segments (CS, DS, ES).

The datasheet for the 8087 co-processor has the following section:

> PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE SUPPORT
>
> Programs for the 8087 can be written in Intel's high-level languages for 8086/8088 and 80186/80188 systems; ASM-86 (the 8086, 8088 assembly language), PL/M-86, FORTRAN-86, and PASCAL-86.

The 80186 added several instructions to the architecture to aid high-level languages.  `PUSHA`, `POPA`, `ENTER`, and `LEAVE` help with subroutine calls.  The `BOUND` instruction was useful for array bounds checking and `switch`-style control statements.  Other instructions unrelated to high-level languages were added as well.

The 80386 added bitfield instructions, which are used in C.

---

The Motorola *MC68000 Microprocessor User's Manual* states:

> 2.2.2  Structured Modular Programming
>
> [...]
> The availability of advanced, structured assemblers and block-structured high-level languages such as Pascal simplifies modular programming.  Such concepts are virtually useless, however, unless parameters are easily transferred between and within software modules that operate on a re-entrant and recursive basis.
> [...]
> The MC68000 provides architectural features that allow efficient re-entrant modular programming.  Two complementary instructions, link and allocate (`LINK`) and unlink (`UNLK`), reduce subroutine call overhead by manipulating linked lists of data areas on the stack.  The move multiple register instruction (`MOVEM`) also reduces subroutine call programming overhead.
> [...]
> Other instructions that support modern structured programming techniques are push effective address (`PEA`), load effective address (`LEA`), return and restore (`RTR`), return from exception (`RTE`), jump to subroutine (`JSR`), branch to subroutine (`BSR`), and return from subroutine (`RTS`).

The 68020 added bitfield instructions, which are used in C.

---

Whereas the above processors *added* instructions to support programming languages, Reduced Instruction-Set Computers (RISC) took the opposite approach.  By analyzing which instructions compilers actually used, they were able to discard many complex instructions that weren't being used.  This allowed the architecture to be simplified, shorten the instruction cycle length, and reduce instructions to one cycle, speeding up processors significantly.

Comment: I interpret the quote from the 8087 manual in a way that the languages listed there (e.g. "PASCAL-86") have been designed to support the (already existing) 8087; the 8087 was not designed in a way to work well with the already existing "PASCAL-86" language.

Comment: Interesting to hear about the 80286 instructions. Would these have been added in anticipation of their use, or to improve the constructs already being used?

Comment: `bound` is not useful for `switch` statements: [the docs for `bound`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bound) say it raises a `#BR` exception if the index is out of bounds.  But in C, even if there's no `default:` case label, an input that doesn't match any case is not undefined-behaviour, it just doesn't run any of the cases.  [What if I don't write default in switch case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8021321)

Comment: The 386 "bitfield" instructions are actually bit*map* instructions, for testing or `bts` test-and-setting/resetting/flipping a *single* bit in a register or in memory.  They're mostly not useful for C `struct` bitfield members.  x86 still has crap-all for bitfield insert/extract compared to ARM `ubfx` / `sbfx` ([un]signed bitfield extract of an immediate range of bits), or PowerPC's very powerful rotate-and-mask immediate instructions like `rlwinm` that can extract a field from anywhere and shift it anywhere into another register.  x86 BMI2 did add `pdep`, but that needs a mask in a register.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: I think it's generally agreed that one of the HLLs 8086 architects had in mind was Pascal.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#The_first_x86_design  says "*According to principal architect Stephen P. Morse, this [instructions supporting nested procedures] was a result of a more software-centric approach than in the design of earlier Intel processors (the designers had experience working with compiler implementations).*"

Comment: @Nathan: `enter` is very slow on modern CPUs, but it was added to support existing language features, specifically nested procedures.  Google found https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse23.html which shows asm call-stack layout inside a nested procedure.  Having the parent frame pointer lets the nested proc see the local variables of the outer scope, which it has access to.  The [x86 `enter` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ENTER.html) replaces multiple instructions especially for entering a nested procedure, making smaller code.  (And on 286, probably faster).

Comment: `enter`, `leave`, `pusha`, `popa`, and `bound` (as well as `insb`/`insw`, `outsb`/`outsw`, and shifts/rotates with immediate byte counts) were introduced by the 186, not the 286. Actual 286 introductions were only the Protected Mode related instructions.

Comment: and to add to @ecm, these instructions are also available in NEC's clones V20 and V30.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter: But note that the typical 186 detection (8086 accepts shift counts in `cl` up to 255, whereas 186 and up mask the shift count from `cl` for an 8-bit or a 16-bit operand with 1Fh) will detect the NECs as 8086 class machines. Therefore [my detection logic](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/release4/source/init.asm#l1702) specifically checks for the NECs using another specific behaviour.

Answer (score 14):

## Null-terminated strings

When C was invented, many different string forms were in used at the same time. String operations were probably handled mostly in software, therefore people can use whatever format they want. Null-terminated string wasn't a new idea, however special hardware support, if any, might not be meant for it.

But later *due to the domination of C*, **other platforms began adding accelerated instructions for the null-terminated format:**

> This had some influence on CPU instruction set design. Some CPUs in the 1970s and 1980s, such as the Zilog Z80 and the DEC VAX, had dedicated instructions for handling length-prefixed strings. However, as the NUL-terminated string gained traction, CPU designers began to take it into account, as seen for example in IBM's decision to add the "Logical String Assist" instructions to the ES/9000 520 in 1992.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string#History

On x86 Intel introduced many instructions for text processing in SSE4.2, which do things in parallel until the first null-termination character. Before that there was the [`SCAS` - scan string](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd) instruction that can be used to look for the position of the termination character

> ```
> mov ecx, 100                ; search up to 100 characters
> xor eax, eax                ; search for 0
> mov edi, offset string      ; search this string
> repe scas byte ptr [edi]    ; scan bytes looking for 0 (find end of string)
> jnz toolong                 ; not found
> sub edi, (offset string) + 1 ; calculate length
> ```
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190130-00/?p=100825

We all know that [nowadays it's a bad idea](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). Unfortunately it was baked into C, hence used by every modern platform and can't be changed anymore. Luckily we have `std::string` in C++

---

The use of a string with some termination character seems already existed on the [PDP-7 where people can choose the termination character](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp7/PDP-7_AsmMan.pdf)

> The string is terminated by the second occurrence of the delimiting character chosen by the user
>
> http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp7/PDP-7_AsmMan.pdf

However a **real null-termination character** [can be seen in used on the PDP-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-8#Subroutines) (see the last line in the code block). Then the `ASCIZ` keyword was introduced in the assembly language for PDP-10/11

> Null-terminated strings were produced by the .ASCIZ directive of the PDP-11 assembly languages and the ASCIZ directive of the MACRO-10 macro assembly language for the PDP-10. These predate the development of the C programming language, but other forms of strings were often used.

The B language, which appeared in 1969 and became the precursor to C, might be influenced by that and uses a special character for termination, although I'm not sure which one was chosen

> In BCPL, the first packed byte contains the number of characters in the string; in B, there is no count and strings are terminated by a special character, which B spelled *e
>
> [Dennis M. Ritchie, *Development of the C Language*](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)

## Further reading

- [What's the rationale for null terminated strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4418708/995714)
- [How did the PDP-8 handle strings?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5840/1981)
- [What's the rationale for null terminated strings? on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3sogkw/whats_the_rationale_for_null_terminated_strings/)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Representations

Comment: If you argue "C uses it because..." you're not providing an answer to the question, but rather the opposite

Comment: @tofro PDP affects C design decision, but C affects development of other hardware platforms. Those are 2 separate processes

Comment: No. C was not designed in any way for the PDP-11. This is a common myth. Most of the features of C that people say were designed for the PDP-11 existed before the language was ported to that platform.

Comment: @JeremyP But they existed very specific on DEC platforms. Can't find any auto increment on a /360 or most other computers - similar character based moves with flags set according to the character transfered.

Comment: What is explained here is how C was influenced by a specific machine feature, not the other way around, as it has been asked by the OP.

Comment: @Raffzahn C was not developed with specific features of the PDP 11 in mind. For example, the `++` and `--` operators were introduced *before* C was ported to the PDP 11. [Read it from the man himself](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).

Comment: @JeremyP Erm, have you tried to read my comment before replying ? I didn't say PDP-11, but DEC. But when it comes to characters it's the PDP-11 where the zero termination happened. After all, the char type was only introduced into B when it got retargeted to produce PDP-11 code. Which also was before C was even fully defined - definition ( and move move from B to C) happened on the PDP-11. Not on any other machine. Further retargeting happened thereafter. **Hint: Read the very link you gave :))**

Comment: @Raffzahn The link I gave only *speculates* that the `++` and `--` operators may have been inspired by the auto increment cells in a PDP-7 but they weren't actually used in the implementation. The `char` type was introduced because the PDP-11 had enough power for more high level language facilities. The idea of using a terminator for strings (as opposed to a count) comes from B. There's no reference in the article to taking advantage of special string manipulation instructions in the PDP-7.

Comment: Besides the fact that "PDP machines" covers a huge range of incompatible architectures, I am not aware of an ASCIZ type in the hardware.  There are certainly uses of null-terminated strings in software; if memory hasn't faulted out, various TTY output UUOs in TOPS-10 used that convention.  But maybe I'm wrong and the PDP-7 had some sort of hardware leaning towards null-termination.

Comment: @JeremyP The link describes the timeline quite well, especially thatth C development took place *after* moving to the PDP-11. Also, the usage of 0 as string terminator isn't based on some 'string operations' but the fact, that on a PDP-11 the flags get set according to the byte moved. here notably the zero flag (similar for test). Thus determinating the end of a string is a build in feature, as long as zero is used as terminator.

Comment: re: "PDP-7 where people can choose the termination character".  Is this referring to the ability to say TEXT /FOO/ or TEXT "FOO" or TEXT QFOOQ?  This was common with DEC assemblers. The delimiters have the same standing as double-quotes in C source code, i.e., they're not part of the text string emitted into the object code.  Such practice is the "other" way of handling the problem of wanting to use your string delimiter inside the delimited string (fhe more common one today being an escape char).

Comment: @Raffzahn They chose to use a termination character rather than a length field for their own reasons and they simply took advantage of the PDP-11 instructions when they ported their compiler to the PDP-11. 0 would be an obvious choice on any computer because even the simplest machine has the ability to test if the content of a location is zero.

Comment: @JeremyP If you don't see the advantage of an **implied** test for zero to use zero as a terminator over any other, than it's hard to continue any further argument. Most other CPU did **not** have a feature of setting flags according to a byte moved. If their languages (and OS) had to use a termination character they usually went for a standard one like ETX. On  machines with block move instructions used wherever possible fixed length or length terminated. Unix (and C) is quite out of the ordinary here. Only because it is standard thinking nowadays doesn't mean it was that way when introduced.

Answer (score 13):

Over time, there have been various language-specific CPUs, some so dedicated that it would be awkward to use them for a different language. For example, the Harris RTX-2000 was designed to run **Forth**.  One could almost say it and other Forth CPUs were the language in hardware form. I'm not saying they understand the language, but they are designed to execute it at the "assembler" level.

Early on, Forth was known for being extremely memory efficient, fast, and, for programmers who could think bass-ackwards, quick to develop in. Having a CPU that could execute it almost directly was a no-brainer. However, memory got cheaper, CPU's got quicker, and programmers who liked [thinking Forth](http://thinking-forth.sourceforge.net/) got scarcer.  (How many folks still use calculators in reverse Polish notation mode?)

Comment: What does "bass-ackwards" mean?

Comment: @wilson I suspect it's a Forth joke, but it went over my head too.

Comment: @Wilson Move the 'b' 4 characters to the right. Logic in Forth is opposite to most other languages. Parameters are generally on the stack and used in an **object object action** order. Compare this to **action(object1, object2)** order of most other languages. I mentioned RPN calculators because they are the same way. Instead of **3*(2+5)=**, you would use **3 2 5 + ***.

Comment: @Neil Couldn't edit previous comment in time. The last phrase should be  in bold: 3 2 5 + * (No parenthesis needed because you think on the stack.)

Comment: I was thinking of Forth almost as soon as I saw the question, but I didn't know a specific Forth-optimized processor so I didn't post an answer.

Comment: @Wilson, bass-ackwards is a non technical joke.  It translates to "ass backwards", implying doing things in a strange reverse order such as walking backwards, with your ass in front.  If you type it bass-ackwards, the joke becomes self referential.

Comment: For other bass-ackwards computers, see the English Electric [KDF9](http://www.findlayw.plus.com/KDF9/). Rather than 'an accumulator' in the manner of its contemporaries, it had a 16-deep nesting store ('stack' to the youth of today) for expression evaluation. The arithmetic orders were zero-address. Note this was not a full stack in the manner of the B5000; it was more limited in applicability.

Comment: On a more hobby and somewhat less retro front, the [J1](http://www.excamera.com/sphinx/fpga-j1.html) is another Forth-optimized CPU.

Answer (score 13):

Arguably, VLIW architectures were designed mainly for smart compilers. They rely on efficient building of individual very complex instructions (a single "instruction" can do many things at the same time), and while it's not impossible to write the code manually, the idea was that you could get better performance for your applications by using a better compiler, rather than having to upgrade your CPU.

In principle, the difference between e.g. a x86 superscalar CPU and something like SHARC or i860 is that x86 achieves instruction level parallelism at runtime, while SHARC is a very simple CPU design (comparatively) that relies on the compiler. In both cases, there's many tricks to reorder instructions, rename registers etc. to allow multiple instructions to run at the same time, while still appearing to execute them sequentially. The VLIW approach would be especially handy in theory for platforms like JVM or .NET, which use a just-in-time compiler - every update to .NET or JVM could make all your applications faster by allowing better optimizations. And of course, during compilation, the compiler has a lot better idea of what all of your application is trying to do, while the runtime approach only ever has a small subset to work with, and has to rely on techniques like statistical branch prediction.

In practice, the approach of having the CPU decide won out. This does make the CPUs incredibly complex, but it's a lot easier to just buy a new better CPU than to recompile or update all your applications; and frankly, it's a lot easier to sell a compatible CPU that just runs your applications faster :)

Comment: RE: your last point. Yes, they're easy to sell, but darn hard to deliver!

Comment: JIT compilers need to run *quickly*, and probably don't have time to find / create as much instruction-level parallelism as possible.  If you've looked at x86 asm created by current JVM jitters, well there's a reason Intel and AMD design their CPUs to be able to chew through lots of instructions quickly.  Modern JITs create extra ILP by wasting instructions :P  [Why is 2 \* (i \* i) faster than 2 \* i \* i in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/93815885) is hopefully at the lower end of HotSpot JVM code quality, but it misses huge amounts of asm-level micro-optimizations.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, I didn't mean we'd use those compilers just in time - .NET supports native image precompilation. The point is that you could do recompile all the native images after updating the runtime (ideally in the background, of course), without requiring the company that produces the application to provide a new build of their software. That said, the latest JIT compiler for .NET is pretty impressive in both speed and the code it produces - though it certainly does have its quirks (my 3D software renderer was a bit impeded by the floating point overhead :D).

Comment: Yeah that works, and might be a way for closed-source software to effectively get the benefit of being ahead-of-time compiled with `-O3 -march=native` to take full advantage of the target CPU.  Like what open-source software in any language can do, e.g. Gentoo Linux compiles packages from source when you install.

Comment: In the late 90s I worked with a VLIW system based on custom silicon (the forerunner is somewhat described at https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/visual/1992/2897/00/00235189.pdf) and it had a custom compiler with some interesting features. All variables (unless otherwise qualified) were *static* which led to some interesting discussions on occasion. The system had up to 320 parallel processors doing video on demand for up to 2000 streams.

Answer (score 13):

Some ARM CPUs used to have partial support for executing Java bytecode in hardware with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle Direct Bytecode eXecution (DBX).

With modern JITing JVMs, that became obsolete, so there was later a variant of Thumb2 mode (compact 16-bit instructions) called ThumbEE designed as a JIT target for managed languages like Java and C# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Thumb_Execution_Environment_(ThumbEE)

Apparently ThumbEE has automatic NULL-pointer checks, and an array-bounds instruction.  But that was deprecated, too, in 2011.

Answer (score 11):

Arguably, the relatively simple logical structure of DO loops in Fortran motivated the development of vector hardware on the early Cray and Cyber supercomputers. There may be some "chicken and egg" between hardware and software development though, since CDC Fortran included array slicing operations to encourage programmers to write "logic-free" loops long before that syntax became standardized in Fortran 90.

Certainly the Cray XMP hardware enhancements compared with the Cray 1, such as improved "chaining" (i.e. overlapping in time) of vector operations, vector mask instructions, and gather/scatter vector addressing, were aimed at improving the performance of typical code written in "idiomatic" Fortran.

The need to find a way to overcome the I/O bottlenecks caused by faster computation, without the prohibitive expense of large fast memory, led to the development of the early Cray SSD storage devices as an intermediate level between main memory conventional disk and tape storage devices. Fortran I/O statements made it easy to read and write a random-access file as if it were a large two-dimensional array of data.

See section 2 of http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/ccd/supercomputers/p005.htm for an 1988 paper by the head of the Cray XMP design team.

There was a downside to this, in that the performance of the first Cray C compilers (and hence the first implementation of the Unix-like Cray operating system UNICOS) was abysmal, since the hardware had no native character-at-a-time instructions, and there was little computer science theory available to attempt to vectorize idiomatic "C-style" loops with a relatively unstructured combination of pointer manipulation and logical tests, compared with Fortran's more rigidly structured DO loops.

Comment: If the hardware didn't have character at a time instructions, leading to poor C compiler performance, then would it have been the case that the next iterations of the hardware added such instructions to improve compiler performance?

Comment: I've used TI DSPs which include a hardware instruction that behaves very much like a "do" loop.  The hardware has three relevant registers and a flag: loop count, loop end, loop start, and loop enable.  The "RPT" instruction loads the "loop end" register with the value an immediate operand, loads "loop start" with the address of the following instruction, and sets the "loop enable" flag.  User code must set "loop count" beforehand.  Any time the program counter equals "loop end" and "loop enable" is set, the DSP will decrement "loop count" and load the program counter with "loop start".

Comment: If the loop counter gets decremented past zero, the loop enable flag will be cleared, so the loop will exit after the next repetition.  TI's compiler is configurable to use the looping feature to improve performance (interrupts would only need to safe/restore its state if they use the feature themselves, so it's usually better to simply disable the feature within interrupt service routines than to save/restore the necessary registers).

Comment: @Nathan: DEC Alpha AXP did that: first 2 silicon versions didn't have byte load / byte store.  Instead, string functions were expected to operate a word at a time, if necessary using bitfield instructions to unpack / repack but the designers argued they wanted to encourage more efficient `strlen` and similar functions that checked a whole 64-bit chunk for any zero bytes with bithacks.  3rd-gen Alpha added byte load/store, but user-space code still generally avoided it in case it would run on older machines and be emulated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Alpha#Byte-Word_Extensions_(BWX)

Comment: Some modern DSPs only have word-addressable memory.  C implementations on those usually use `CHAR_BIT=32` (or 16 for 16-bit machines), instead of doing software read-modify-write of a 32-bit word to implement an 8-bit `char`.  But DSPs don't need to run general-purpose text-processing software like Unix systems.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The question of whether or not an architecture supports octet-addressable storage is IMHO influenced a lot by programming languages.  There aren't a whole lot of tasks where a lack of octet-addressable storage would need to be a problem if a language had a means of copying a range of words while shifting them, but there are a lot of tasks whose natural specification in many programming languages would be impractical to support without octet-addressable storage.

Answer (score 11):

Another specific example of hardware design to match the languages was Rekursiv, which was designed to implement object oriented language features in hardware.

Our Rekursiv has been preserved in a museum.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rekursiv

Comment: Ha, I'd never heard of the Rekursiv, but the name made me immediately think that it had to have something to do with Linn.

Comment: how did the hardware optimize for oo? only think I can think of is maybe perfecting the vtable call

Answer (score 10):

I recall, back in the 80’s, and referenced in the Wikipedia article, [Bellmac 32](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellmac_32) CPU, which became the AT&T Western Electric WE32100 CPU was supposedly designed for the C programming language.

This CPU was used by AT&T in their 3B2 line of Unix systems. There was also a single board VME bus version of it that some third parties used. Zilog also came out with a line of Unix systems using this chip - I think they were a second source for it for AT&T.

I did a lot of work with these in the 80’s and probably early 90’s. It was pretty much a dog in terms of performance, if I remember.

Answer (score 10):

Another example is the decline of **[binary-coded decimal instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#Other_computers_and_BCD)**

In the past it was common for computers to be decimal or have instructions for decimal operations. For example [x86 has AAM, AAD, AAA, FBLD...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_BCD_opcode) for operating on packed, unpacked and 10-byte BCD values. Many other classic architectures also have similar features

> Several microprocessor families offer limited decimal support. For example, the 80x86 family of microprocessors provide instructions to convert one-byte BCD numbers (packed and unpacked) to binary format before or after arithmetic operations.[<sup>[3]</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20070715175818/http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/Page_TechDocs/MASMDoc/ProgrammersGuide/Chap_06.htm) These operations were not extended to wider formats and hence are now slower than using 32-bit or wider BCD 'tricks' to compute in BCD (see [[1]](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/%7Ejones/bcd/bcd.html)). The x87 FPU has instructions to convert 10-byte (18 decimal digits) packed decimal data, although it then operates on them as floating-point numbers.
>
> The Motorola 68000 provided instructions for BCD addition and subtraction;[<sup>[4]</sup>](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf) as does the 6502. In the much later 68000 family-derived processors, these instructions were removed when the Coldfire instruction set was defined, and all IBM mainframes also provide BCD integer arithmetic in hardware. The Zilog Z80, Motorola 6800 and its derivatives, together with other 8-bit processors, and also the Intel x86 family have special instructions that support conversion to and from BCD. The Psion Organiser I handheld computer’s manufacturer-supplied software implemented its floating point operations in software using BCD entirely. All later Psion models used binary only, rather than BCD.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_computer#More_modern_computers

However they're rarely used, since *modern languages often don't have a way to access those instructions*. They either lack a decimal integer type completely (like C or Pascal), or doesn't have a decimal type that can map cleanly to BCD instructions

The result is that **BCD instructions started to disappear**. In x86 they're micro-coded, therefore very slow, which makes people further avoid them. Later AMD removed BCD instructions in x64-64. Other manufacturers did the same in newer versions of their architectures. Having said that, a remnant of BCD operations is still there in the [FLAGS register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) in x86-64 and many other platforms that use flags: the [half-carry flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-carry_flag). Newly implemented architectures like ARM, MIPS, Sparc, RISC-V also didn't get any BCD instructions and most of them don't use a flag register

In fact C and C++ allow `float`, `double` and `long double` to be decimal, however none of the implementations use it for the default floating-point types, because modern computers are all binary and are bad at decimal operations. Very few architectures have decimal floating-point support

Many C and C++ compilers do have decimal floating-point types as an *extension*, such as [gcc with `_Decimal32`, `_Decimal64`, and `_Decimal128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html). Similarly some other modern languages also have [decimal types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_data_type), however those are mostly big floating-point types for financial or scientific problems and not an integer BCD type. For example [`decimal` in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) is a floating-point type with the mantissa stored in binary, thus BCD instructions would be no help here. Arbitrary-precision decimal types like `BigInteger` in C# and `BigDecimal` in Ruby or Java also store the mantissa as binary instead of decimal for performance. A few languages do have a **fixed-point** decimal monetary type, but the significant part is also in binary

That said, a few floating-point formats can still be stored in BCD or a related form. For example the mantissa in [IEEE-754 decimal floating-point types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) can be stored in either [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_integer_decimal) or [DPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_packed_decimal) (a highly-packed decimal format which can then be converted to BCD easily). However I doubt that decimal IEEE-754 libraries use BCD instructions, because they're often not exist at all in modern computers, or in case they really exist they'd be extremely slow

> BCD was used in many early decimal computers, and is implemented in the instruction set of machines such as the IBM System/360 series and its descendants, Digital Equipment Corporation's VAX, the Burroughs B1700, and the Motorola 68000-series processors. Although BCD per se is not as widely used as in the past and is no longer implemented in newer computers' instruction sets (such as ARM; x86 does not support its BCD instructions in long mode any more), decimal fixed-point and floating-point formats are still important and continue to be used in financial, commercial, and industrial computing, where subtle conversion and fractional rounding errors that are inherent in floating point binary representations cannot be tolerated.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#Other_computers_and_BCD

- [Does a compiler use all x86 instructions?](http://pepijndevos.nl/2016/08/24/x86-instruction-distribution.html)
- [Does a compiler use all x86 instructions? (2010)](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12352959)
- [Do modern x86 processors have native support for decimal floating point arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47000444/995714)

Comment: Was it a case that these instructions were rarely used to begin with, or just that alternative implementations (if used) like you mentioned better suited to modern languages?

Comment: Bizarrely, some microcontroller designers are incorporating BCD-based real-time-clock-calendar circuitry into ARM devices.  That might be handy if for some reason software wanted to read a time and show it as a hex dump, but it adds silly overhead when doing almost anything else.

Comment: They were never common on high level languages. The only notable language with BCD support is COBOL, which is still in use today by financial institutions. However they're used a lot in hand-written assembly in the past. Even nowadays BCD is still commonly used in microcontrollers as @supercat said, because they don't have a fast multiplier/divider and with BCD they can do arithmetic in decimal directly (like outputting numbers to 7-segment LEDs) instead of messing around with divide by 10 to convert to decimal

Comment: @phuclv: The only place I've seen any new microcontroller designs use BCD is in real-time clock/calendar modules.  Even in applications that need to display large numbers, it's more practical to use one byte per digit or use an optimized function whose behavior is equivalent to `int temp=256*remainder + *p; *p=temp/10; remainder = temp % 10; *p++;` which can be implemented efficiently even on platforms that lack "divide" instructions, and can be used to convert any size binary number to decimal fairly easily.

Comment: AMD didn't deprecate BCD instructions in x86-64, they *omitted* them from 64-bit long mode and left them totally unchanged in other modes, including compat mode (with the same performance as K7).  "Deprecate" implies still present but not recommended. The deprecation was earlier and gradual, by Intel and AMD making them slower in 16/32-bit modes, not by the x86-64 ISA. AMD K7 already had heavily microcoded AAA/DAA, and according to https://agner.org/optimize/, same ops/lat/tput numbers as on K8 (x86-64).  P6 (PPro / PII /PIII) has single-uop AAA / DAA.

Comment: But Pentium 4 had slow BCD instructions, so that was around when Intel first introduced a CPU that didn't try to make them efficient.  But later P6-family CPUs up to Nehalem had single-uop (3c latency, 1c throughput) implementations of AAA AAS DAA DAS.  Other than P4, Intel didn't *really* give up on them until SnB-family in 2011, when they redesigned a lot of internals.  Or Atom has *extremely* slow BCD, like 20c latency.

Comment: Fun-fact: AAM is literally just 8-bit division by an immediate, and is just as fast as `div r/m8` even on modern CPUs (because AAM can use the same divider hardware, but the dividend is only 8-bit instead of 16),  It puts the quotient and remainder in opposite registers from `div`, though, so actually it costs one extra uop more than `div r/m8` on some CPUs, presumably doing a div and then swapping.  But on some Intel CPUs it's still slightly faster than `div r8`, especially if you count `mov bl, imm8` against `div`.  Of course if you care about perf not size, you use a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes "deprecate" is a wrong word choice. I'll edit it

Comment: @supercat indeed BCD is common in RTC chips, because many of them don't use a global time counter but increase each decimal digits separately. BCD is fast on 2-digit operations and time values uses 2 digits for each component which makes them a good candidate for BCD. New MCU architectures like PIC or AVR still contain the [half-carry flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-carry_flag) for packed BCD operations like that. For wider types people typically use binary anyway because they code in a higher language.

Comment: @phuclv: Cascading eleven counters that each count to 15 behind an asynchronous counter that counts to seven would seem like it should be just about the easiest thing imaginable.  I can't see how the day/date logic of an RTCC could be any easier than a simple straight sequence of power-of-two counters.

Comment: You're saying BCD arithmetic wasn't used by compilers. While you are correct that C doesn't have a BCD integer type, Turbo Pascal 3 for DOS  (probably the most wide-spread compiler of its aera was available in a version that supported BCD integer types.

Comment: @tofro fair enough. I didn't knew that there was a Pascal version with BCD. But a high-level language with BCD support is rare enough that pretty much no one knows or cares about it

Comment: [Why do real-time clock chips use BCD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/12606/27052)

Comment: @tofro: TP3 was available with a run-time library version that used BCD math for its one and only floating-point type.  I suspect the only actual change to the compiler was the size of the `REAL` type and the formatting of floating-point literals.  The language itself would otherwise be agnostic to the floating-point format.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, definitely. A very good example is how Motorola moved from the 68k architecture to the (somewhat) compatible ColdFire range of CPUs. (It is also an example of how such an evolution might go wrong, but that is another story).

The Motorola Coldfire range of CPUs and Microcontrollers was basically a 68000 CPU32 core with lots of instructions and addressing modes removed that "normal" C compilers wouldn't use frequently (like arithmetic instructions on byte and word operands, some complex addressing modes and addressing modes that act only on memory in favor of registers,...). They also simplified the supervisor mode model and removed some rarely used instructions completely. The whole instruction set was "optimized for C and C++ compilers" (This is how Motorola put it) and the freed up chip space used to train the CPUs for performance (like with adding larger data and instruction caches).

In the end, the changes made the CPUs quite a bit too incompatible for customers to stay within the product family, and the MC68k range of CPUs went towards its demise.

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out what you meant by "addressing modes that act only on memory"; these are very useful to a C compiler?

Comment: The 68k has a number of very complex addressing modes, like "memory indirect with register offsets and postincrement" that contemporary C compilers didn't/couldn't/wouldn't use according to Motorola and were removed in the Coldfire architecture..

Comment: That sounds like `*ptr[offset++]` to me?

Comment: that's more like array[x++ + sizeof(array[0]) * y]. Compilers of that time apparently weren't able to make use of such complex addressing modes. Might be different with today's compilers.

Answer (score 8):

Yet another example: The Prime minicomputer had a segmented architecture, and anything in segment 07777 was a null pointer (Prime used octal, and the top 4 bits of the 16-bit word had other uses).  Segment 0 was a kernel segment, and just loading 0 into a segment register in user code was an access violation.  This would have been fine in properly written C (`int* p = 0;` stored bit pattern 7777/0 into p).

However it turns out that a *lot* of C code assumes that if you `memset` a block of memory to all bits zero, that any contained pointers will have been set to `NULL`.  They eventually had to add a whole new instruction called TCNP (Test C Null Pointer).

Comment: C is just too flexible for its own good, and/or its standard library sucks.  e.g. `memset` can only take a repeating pattern 1 `char` wide, so the only portable way to fill an array with `NULL` is an actual loop.  But that's not efficient on any implementation that doesn't recognize it as a memset idiom or auto-vectorize it.  So basically C doesn't give you the tools to conveniently deal with all the possible unusual implementations it allows, making it really easy and common to write non-portable code.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You can write `static const foo_t zero_foo = {0};` and then memcpy from that - but that does waste a chunk of memory, and doesn't help if people allocate stuff with `calloc` (and it means that zeroing the memory needs twice the memory bandwidth).

Comment: Ok, so not the only portable way, but there's no portable way that's as efficient as `memset` on typical implementations.  Having arbitrary-sized arrays of NULL pointers of each type is totally impractical.  (C does allow different object-representations for different pointer types, right?  So even an arbitrary-sized array of `(void*)NULL` isn't enough.)  Or you could loop in chunks of memcpying 1k at a time so you can have bounded sizes for your copy sources, but then you probably bloat each zeroing site with a loop around memcpy if the size isn't provably smaller than 4kiB at runtime.

Comment: And dirtying cache for these stupid source arrays is just horrible.

Comment: "C does allow different object-representations for different pointer types, right?" - Yes, and the Prime used this.  A pointer was segment + word offset, unless you needed a character pointer (or void ptr) - when one of the bits in the segment word was set, indicating that there was a *third* word which was the bit offset (which was always 0 or 8).  It's a lovely machine for violating people's assumptions about "how all computers work".  It used ASCII, but ASCII is seven-bit, and they always *set* the top bit!

Answer (score 7):

Another interesting example are Java processors, CPUs that execute (a subset of) Java Virtual Machine bytecode as their instruction sets.

If you’re interested enough to ask this question, you might want to read one of the later editions of Andrew Tanenbaum’s textbook, *Structured Computer Organization*¹, in which he walks the reader step-by-step through the design of a simple Java processor.

¹ Apparently not the third edition or below.  It’s in Chapter 4 of the fifth edition.

Comment: You must be thinking of a particular edition of Tanenbaum's textbook. I have the third edition which doesn't mention Java anywhere -- not surprisingly since it was published 6 years before Java 1.0. (The copyright dates in the third edition are 1976, 1984, 1990).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, you're correct. Let me check.

Comment: While I don't see much use for a processor running Java bytecode vs. using a JIT, garbage-collected languages could benefit from some features that I've not seen supported in hardware such as support for an cache-efficient lazy bit-set operation with semantics that if synchronization is forced after multiple threads have independently set various bits in the same word, all threads would see all bits that are set.  Bits could only be cleared at a time when all threads that might set them were stopped.  Such a feature would greatly improve the efficiency of maintaining "dirty" flags.

Answer (score 6):

Some more examples of programming languages affecting hardware design:

The MIPS RISC ISA often seems strange to newcomers: instructions like ADD generate exceptions on signed integer overflow. It is necessary to use ADDU, add unsigned, to get the usual 2’s complement wrap.

Now, I wasn’t there at the time, but I conjecture that MIPS provided this behavior because it was designed with the Stanford benchmarks - which were originally written in the Pascal programming language, which requires overflow detection.

The C programming language does not require overflow traps. The MIPSr6 new (circa 2012) ISA gets rid of the integer overflow trapping instructions - at least those with a 16 bit immediate - in order to free up opcode space. I *was* there when this was done.

—

I can testify that programming languages influenced many modern x86 features, at least from P6 onwards. Mainly C/C++; to some extent JavaScript.

Comment: Indeed wiki said that [*integer overflow trapping instructions with 16-bit immediate* were removed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64_Release_6). That's good since no one use `add` or `sub` in MIPS anyway

Comment: Nobody uses MIPS’ trap on overflow instructions. Certainly not C code. But JavaScript requires overflow detection. MIPSr6 added a branch on overflow instruction. But that requires extra code. I conjecture that if OS and JavaScript were defined together, trap on overflow might be better. However, JavaScript engines that want to be portable would not do this.

Comment: autocorrect typo: s/oppose/opcode/.

Comment: There are many purposes for which having a program terminate abnormally would be far preferable to having it produce incorrect output that seems valid.  There are other purposes for which it is useful for a program which receives a mixture of valid and invalid data produce a corresponding mixture of correct and meaningless output, so the presence of invalid data doesn't prevent the program from correctly producing the portions of the output associated with the correct data.  Having both instructions available facilitates both kinds of programming in languages that expose them.

Comment: @supercat and your point is? Trapping on overflow does not necessarily mean terminating the program. In the bad old days we used to have trap handlers that actually did things - like look up the trap PC, and decide what to do.  I.e. trapping can be the exact equivalent of an IF statement - the tradeoff being that the IF statement requires an extra instruction, slowing down the case where IF-overflow does not happen, whereas the trap slows down the case where the IF-overflow happens. And requires cooperation between the compiler and the part of the runtime that handles traps.

Comment: Unfortunately, rather than providing a means by which programmers seeking to perform one or other kind of task can have a compiler provide proper semantics, it's more fashionable for compilers to generate code where the presence of incorrect data that causes overflow may arbitrarily corrupt the portions of the output associated with correct data.  Such programs thus combine the disadvantages of both other approaches.

Comment: @KrazyGlew: Precise overflow trapping semantics are expensive, even with hardware assistance, with much of the cost coming not from the detection of overflow, but rather the inability to reorder any operation that might have side-effects ahead of any operation that might cause overflow.  Making overflow detection inexpensive would require either having loosely specified behavior in case of a trap, or else having a latching overflow flag with loose semantics, which is the approach I'd prefer to see languages take.

Comment: @supercat precise trapping semantics are exactly as costly as making every instruction that you wish to trap in this way a branch.

Comment: @KrazyGlew: That may in some sense be true, but all those branches will add data dependencies all over the place that would otherwise not exist.  Suppose, for example, that an optimizer knows that `slowcalc()` is a function that returns an `int` with no side-effects, some other function `foo` ends with `return slowcalc(x)*slowcalc(y);`.  In the absence of precise overflow-trapping semantics, a compiler could defer computations of `slowcalc()` unless or until some computation that depends upon the result is used in a way that might affect a program's behavior or output. If that never happens...

Comment: ...the computation could be postponed forever (and under the as-if rule, omitted altogether).  Under precise overflow-trapping semantics, however, an implementation would be obligated to compute `slowcalc(x)` and `slowcalc(y)` and determine whether their product is representable as `int` before doing anything else.  Many programs perform a lot of calculations whose results never end up getting used, because performing the calculations unconditionally is cheaper than deciding whether to perform them.  In cases where skipping them would be easy, however, that would be cheaper yet.

Answer (score 4):

## Multi-operand IMUL on x86

Not quite sure if it was *entirely* driven by programming languages, but I believe they must have **high influences** to Intel's decision

Originally there were only `IMUL r/m16` and `IMUL r/m8` that output a product *twice as wide* as the operands. However in reality modern high-level languages generally produce a multiplication result that has the **same type** as the two operands unless you cast the them to a wider type. For example in C if we have `int a` and `int b` then `a*b` will also have type `int`. Same to most other languages. Doing a non-widening multiplication is also faster than getting the full result, so Intel added the 2 and 3-operand forms that don't calculate the high bits

> There are two additional forms for the IMUL instruction which do not fit the above pattern. The first is a two-operand version that follows the pattern for ADD:
>
> ```
>  IMUL    r, r/m      ; d *= s (signed)
> ```
>
> This is a more traditional-looking two-operand instruction² that updates the destination register in place.
>
> There is even a (gasp) three-operand version similar to what you see in other processors.
>
> ```
>  IMUL  r, r/m, i     ; d = s * t (signed)
> ```
>
> This three-operand version accepts an immediate as the third operand, and it's the one the compiler typically generates. For example,
>
> ```
>  IMUL  EAX, ECX, 212 ; EAX = ECX * 212 (signed)
> ```
>
> These additional forms produce only single-precision results, but that's what the C and C++ languages produce, so it fits well with those languages. If you need a double-precision result, then you can use the single-operand MUL and IMUL instructions.
>
> Note that there is no unsigned version of these additional forms. Fortunately, you can use the signed version for unsigned multiplication because the single-precision result is the same for both signed and unsigned multiplication. However, the flags are always set according to the signed result, so you cannot use them to detect unsigned overflow.
>
> In practice, this is not a problem because the C language doesn't give you access to the overflow flags anyway.
>
> [The Intel 80386, part 4: Arithmetic](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190124-00/?p=100775)

Since they're more flexible, fit perfectly with the type model, and don't care about signness (because non-widening multiplication is [the same for signed and unsigned values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34377711/995714)), compilers began to use it exclusively for almost all multiplications. As a result, Intel [focused to optimize even more for those forms of `imul`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14063599/995714#comment33750540_14063665). In fact nowadays single-operand `mul` and `imul` are very rarely used and may be slow on many μarchs. See [Why is `imul` used for multiplying unsigned numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42587607/995714)

Comment: The multi-operand `imul` was often useful for array subscripting.  If a structure takes 28 bytes, and one has the value of `i` cached in `esi`, then evaluating `foo[i].whatever=3` as `imul edi,esi,28 ; mov dword [edi + addressof &foo[0].whatever],5` would save a move compared with having to move esi to eax before doing the multiply.

Answer (score 4):

Not *yet* retro (as of 2019), but on topic: the ARM Cortex-M design was influenced by the C language (may also apply to Cortex-A and -R, but I don't have experience with them).

1. No assembly code is needed for startup. The hardware sets the initial stack pointer at reset and then the compiled code can execute without any "magic" (some exceptions to this may exist depending on the exact hardware).
2. Interrupt handlers are just regular functions from compiler's point of view. They only require specific names, so that the linker can put their vectors in the right place for the NVIC (interrupt controller) to find them. The hardware takes care of stacking and unstacking of registers on ISR entry/exit. Compare that with other architectures (eg. AVR, MSP430, older ARM), where special compiler attributes are needed for interrupt handlers and the compiler has to emit extra code to handle entry/exit.

Comment: Writing a startup handler entirely in C would require a means of generating linker symbols to identify the start and end of the initialized and uninitialized data sections, as well as the whereabouts of the data with which the initialized data section should be loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
More recently, the TPUs (Tensor Processing Units,) designed by Google to accelerate AI work, are designed to efficiently process their TensorFlow language.